# Struggling as to what I need to add into my code so that when the user enters a specific password they get a role (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello here is my code currently, I can type any word or number phrase and it brings up a button which says enter password I click it and it brings up a modal, My issue is I can enter anything into the modal and it accepts it. I want it to only accept a specific password or number phrase and if the password is correct it gives a specific role.

I am unsure what I need to add into my code to make this happen.

```
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton,
    Modal,
    TextInputComponent,
} = require('discord.js');


const TOKEN = 'My Token';
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let button = new MessageActionRow();
    button.addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('verification-button')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setLabel('Enter Password...'),
    );
    message.reply({
        components: [button],
    });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'verification-button') {
            const modal = new Modal()
                .setCustomId('verification-modal')
                .setTitle('Verify yourself')
                .addComponents([
                    new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new TextInputComponent()
                            .setCustomId('verification-input')
                            .setLabel('Answer')
                            .setStyle('SHORT')
                            .setMinLength(4)
                            .setMaxLength(12)
                            .setPlaceholder('111111')
                            .setRequired(true),
                    ),
                ]);

            await interaction.showModal(modal);
        }
    }

    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'verification-modal') {
            const response =
                interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
            interaction.reply(`Yay, your answer is submitted: "${response}"`);
        }
    }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot v13 is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: You never check the value of `response`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'verification-modal') {
            const response =
                interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
            if (response === "Correct answer") {
                interaction.reply(`Yay, your answer is correct: "${response}"`);
                interaction.member.roles.add(...)
            } else {
                interaction.reply(`Oh no, your answer is incorrect: "${response}"`);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm, just added ephemerals too. My next step it to create an embed and add the password button onto that 